# Can you cast bonus action and reaction spells while already casting a spell with a casting time longer than a turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, reactions, spellcasting

Can a bonus action or reaction spell be cast while already casting a spell with a casting time of more than a turn?

(If the bonus action or reaction spell is not a concentration spell.)

I found this on D&D Beyond about spells with [longer casting times](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#LongerCastingTimes):

> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time longer than a single action or reaction, you must spend your action each turn casting the spell, and you must maintain your concentration while you do so. If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don't expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over.

Since this only mentions requiring your action each turn, not bonus actions and reactions, it seems you can still take such actions.

Comment: Heavily related: "[If a Spell has a casting time of 1 minute, what part of the caster's action economy would it take up if it was cast in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108295)"

Comment: Related: [Can I cast reaction spells like Shield or Counterspell when I'm in the middle of casting a spell with a long casting time and don't stop casting it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150359/can-i-cast-reaction-spells-like-shield-or-counterspell-when-im-in-the-middle-of)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Reaction spells yes, bonus action spells no

Bonus action spells have an additional rule that limits spellcasting on the same turn. From the ["Casting a Spell"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) section of the Basic Rules on D&D Beyond:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

This limitation prevents you from casting any spell with a casting time longer than a single action on the same turn, so bonus action spells cannot be used in this manner. This limitation is unique to bonus action spells, though --- reaction spells have no such limitation and can be used even while casting another spell.

Comment: I've now asked the more general question here: "[Does maintaining a spell with a longer casting time count as casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154135)"

Comment: You could cast bonus action cantrips however, of which there are two: Shillelagh and Magic Stone

Comment: So then, the exception that I knew must exist is that you *can* cast any spell as a bonus action if *mending* is the spell you are already casting every turn, since it is a cantrip.

Comment: @Nacht No, because mending doesn't have a casting time of one action.

Comment: @kviiri wow. That was just lazy of me. I guess there's no exceptions then.