# Can you take another action via Action Surge while casting a spell with a casting time longer than one action?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, actions, fighter, spellcasting

To preface, this is for D&D 5e.

This is building upon the answer from [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154131/can-you-cast-bonus-action-and-reaction-spells-while-already-casting-a-spell-with) question, since it did not address my issue completely. I am a Fighter 2 Wizard 10, and am currently casting the spell [Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/private-sanctum) which has a casting time of 10 minutes, or 100 turns.

While focusing on the casting, our party was ambushed by monsters. I decided that instead of fighting, I would continue to cast the spell, using my action every turn as described by the [Longer Casting Times](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#LongerCastingTimes) section of the PHB.

> "...you must spend your action each turn casting the spell, and you must maintain your concentration while you do so. If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don't expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over."

I am a Necromancy Wizard, and am using my bonus action to control my animated undead. However, I also have the [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter) ability from my fighter multiclass dip, which allows me to take another action on my turn. Can I move and use my action surge to attack with a cantrip or weapon, all while still casting Private Sanctum? If so, can I also cast a spell with a casting time of one action while still casting Private Sanctum using this ability?

Comment: @Medix2 perhaps the fact that you have to use your action to cast the spell so you might have to use both actions

Comment: @Medix2 The wording of "Longer Casting Times" is what makes me think you may not be able to. I'll add that to the description of the question

Comment: Related: [If a Spell has a casting time of 1 minute, what part of the caster's action economy would it take up if it was cast in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108295/52137)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It’s an *additional* action - you can use it for anything you like

**Except** casting a concentration spell - that would end your longer casting time spell because you are concentrating on that.

Aside from that, you can use this *additional* action to do any of the things in the PHB including Attack and Cast a Spell, leaving *your* action available for continuing to cast.

Having to use *your* action to continue to cast the spell does not affect your movement in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, part of the question still isn't answered. I'm also trying to determine if I'm able to use movement on each turn while casting the spell. My DM thinks that you cannot move while casting a spell, and I'm trying to find a rule on this in the spellcasting section.

Comment: You can move while maintaining concentration, which is all that's required under Longer Casting Times.  (What use would _alter self_ be if you couldn't move while maintaining it?)

Comment: Is there ant RAW about your use of "additional" in this? It seems like it is just an interpretation of yours without anything backing it up.

Comment: @Eternallord66 Actually, it's right there in the Action Surge description. "On your turn, you can take one additional action."

Comment: @eternallord66 At the very least "You must use your action" ≠ "You must use every action you have", nearly everything is written assuming you have only one action and it is referred to regularly as "your action" (though this could be stated in the answer here)

Comment: @Akira_Kurusu It would be helpful to actually include how it is different by RAW in the answer. Otherwise it is just an interpretation.

Comment: @Medix2 That is an interpretation and not RAW. There may be something somewhere that shows that this interpretation is correct and if so, it should be included.